# "Numeric value '' is not recognized" - what column?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to insert data from a staging table into the master table. The table has nearly 300 columns, and is a mix of data-typed Varchars, Integers, Decimals, Dates, etc.

Snowflake gives the unhelpful error message of "***Numeric value '' is not recognized***"

I have gone through and cut out various parts of the query to try and isolate where it is coming from. After several hours and cutting every column, it is still happening.

Does anyone know of a Snowflake diagnostic query (like Redshift has) which can tell me a *specific column* where the issue is occurring?

Answer (score 2):

You can run a query like this one to find mismatched types between your two tables:

```
SELECT a.column_name,
       a.data_type,
       b.data_type
FROM information_schema.columns a
LEFT JOIN information_schema.columns b ON a.column_name = b.column_name
WHERE a.table_schema = 'schema1'
  AND a.table_name = 'table1'
  AND b.table_schema = 'schema2'
  AND b.table_name = 'table2'
  AND a.data_type <> b.data_type
```

The output will look like this:

```
+-------------------+-----------+-------------+
| COLUMN_NAME       | DATA_TYPE | DATA_TYPE_2 |
+-------------------+-----------+-------------+
| SOME_COLUMN       | FLOAT     | TEXT        |
+-------------------+-----------+-------------+
| SOME_OTHER_COLUMN | FLOAT     | TEXT        |
+-------------------+-----------+-------------+
```

Comment: It's almost always on the join columns so just check those using this

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not at the point you're at.  If you went back to the COPY INTO that loaded the data, you'd be able to use VALIDATE() function to get better information to the record and byte-offset level.

I would query your staging table for just the numeric fields and look for blanks, or you can wrap all of your fields destined for numeric fields with try_to_number() functions.  A bit tedious, but might not be too bad if you don't have a lot of numbers.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_to_decimal.html

As a note, when you stage, you should try and use the NULL_IF options to get rid of bad characters and/or try to load them into stage using the actual datatypes in your stage table, so you can leverage the VALIDATE() function to make sure the data types are correct before loading into Snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

Query your staging using try_to_number() and/or try_to_decimal() for number and decimal fields of the table and the use the minus to get the difference

Select $1,$2,...$300 from @stage

minus

Select $1,try_to_number($2)...$300 from@stage

If any number  field has a string that cannot be converted then it will be null and then minus should return those rows which have a problem..Once you get the rows then try to analyze the columns in the result set for errors.

Answer (score 0):

TIL how to debug this issue via Query Profile in Snowflake, so I thought I'd share. Most likely for the OP the issue is in the original insert/copy where he did a `CAST` operation instead of a `TRY_CAST` in the query, which is safer when loading data (e.g. using `TRY_CAST(ID as INTEGER)`
instead of `ID::INTEGER`).

But on the debugging, if this is happening in a complex query, you can use the [Query Profile tool inside the Snowflake web UI](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-query-profile). This allows you to [view execution by node](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-query-profile#profile-overview-operator-details), and find the execution step that is throwing the error.

While you can't actually isolate the column per se, you can isolate the statement that is failing, which should help you find the specific column causing the error.